# How to display an animated icon during Ajax request processing - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am trying to display an loading indicator for every ajax request, I working in a rails 3 app.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="loading-indicator">
 <%= image_tag("loading.gif", :id => "loading-indicator", :style => "display:none") %>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#loading-indicator {
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   top: 10px;
 }
```

**loading.js:** which I placed in assest/javascripts/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
        $('#loading-indicator').show();
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
        $('#loading-indicator').hide();
    });
});
```

**My application.js looks like this:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

It dosent work, nothing shows up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd start by taking a look at the JS error console to see if anything went wrong! Also double check that loading.js is properly loaded by execamining the header of the generated HTML

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto It is properly loaded and I didnt get  error in firebug

Comment: Is it a GET or POST? Also, which type of html element (i.e. **a**, **button**, **input** etc) are you trying to ajaxify? The rails UJS file sets [different ajax defaults](http://blog.madebydna.com/all/code/2011/12/05/ajax-in-rails-3.html) depending on the category of html element

Comment: @stephenmurdoch It is a <a> element, check my previous question: bit.ly/Or8agT

Comment: Can you replace your show and hide calls with alerts just to make sure the functions are getting executed?

Comment: @stephenmurdoch when using remote => true, the GET method is the deault for links.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I usually have this piece of code saved to situations like these:

```
$(function() {
  $('#loading-indicator')
    .hide()  // hide it initially.
    .ajaxStart(function() {
      $(this).show(); // show on any Ajax event.
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
      $(this).hide(); // hide it when it is done.
  });
});
```

**--- EDIT ---**

This will not work with the latest versions of jQuery. As of jQuery 1.8, the `.ajaxStart()` method should only be attached to `document`. The code should therefore look as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $('#loading-indicator').hide();  // hide it initially.
  $(document)  
    .ajaxStart(function() {
      $('#loading-indicator').show(); // show on any Ajax event.
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
      $('#loading-indicator').hide(); // hide it when it is done.
  });
});
```

Comment: soory mate it didnt work. - maybe I have to add some duration? it loads to fast?

Comment: Odd. This example works flawless in all cases. Check for syntax errors, identation, etc. And check the browser error log too. =]

Comment: check my previous question:http://bit.ly/Or8agT , doset the script respond to click event also?

Comment: It would only work if an Ajax request is made. Ex.: a POST, GET, PUT, DELETE made to the server. This would not work for a click event that just manipulates some random DOM.

Comment: but if you check the question closely, that process is a ajax call.

Comment: Do you know how I can show only the loading indicator and when all the request is finished.. then hide the loading indicator and show the content?

Comment: This will not work with the latest versions of jQuery. As of jQuery 1.8, the `.ajaxStart()` method should only be attached to `document`.

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich Feel free to add this to the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You technically can't use the same "id" twice for two different elements in the same document. i.e. you are assigning id="loading-indicator" to both the div and the img tags; this might be causing JS DOM selection and manipulation errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the css style tag and the css position

I fix it by doing this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="loading-indicator">
 <%= image_tag("loading.gif", :id => "loading-indicator") %>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#loading-indicator {
   left: 10px;
   top: 10px;
 }
```